# how to get email of dropbox account during login process?

Tags: android, dropbox

I used "dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1.jar" and tried to get email:

```
AndroidAuthSession session = buildSession();
mApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);


mApi.getSession().startOAuth2Authentication(myactivity.this);
```

however, i can only get back the displayname:

```
String email = mApi.accountInfo().displayName.toString();
```

how i can get the email user uses to authenticate with dropboxAPI?
I appreciate any reply. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use reflection to get JSONObject which contains email info

```
public static JSONObject getJson(DbxAccountInfo info) {
    Class<?> accountClass;
    Field rawJson = null;
    try {
        accountClass = Class.forName(info.getClass().getName());
        rawJson = accountClass.getDeclaredField("rawJson");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        Log.d("myLogs", e1.getMessage() + " exception");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    rawJson.setAccessible(true);
    JSONObject json = null;
    try {
        json = new JSONObject((String)rawJson.get(info));
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Does not work with the current Dropbox Android API, I get a `NoSuchFieldException`. Any other idea?